# How do I fix Function mysql_list_tables() is deprecated?

Tags: php, mysql, deprecated

I'm trying to add a voting system for my website, and I get this error:

```
Deprecated: Function mysql_list_tables() is deprecated in /home/yokoscap/public_html/vote/classes/vote.class.php on line 11
Access denied for user 'yokoscap'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm new to PHP and MySQL, so if you could dumb it down/help me fix it it'd be great.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/3mfpFwW7) the code paste, I thought it was too big to go in here so I uploaded to pastebin.

Comment: If you google `mysql_list_tables()` , you can simply find the solution

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 4):

Did you [check the manual](http://php.net/mysql_list_tables)? There is a complete example on a replacement for it:

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';

if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Could you possibly implement this into the code I've got? Im sorry, I really don't know php too well

Comment: @Cody - This is a great time to learn then `:)` Nobody is going to write your code for you here.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I replaced it with this 
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db";

It seems to work with the pre exisging code. Thanks so much!

Comment: +1 also mysql_* are deprecated too in php >=5.5 :P

Answer (score 2):

use this sql query

```
show tables from dbname
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_list_tables()` function has been deprecated since PHP 4.3.7 (!) because it's entirely too specific.

To get a list of tables in the current database, run a `SHOW TABLES` query. It's a perfectly normal query; you don't need a special function just to do that.

Comment: How would I do that, I'm really sorry, I don't have a clue with PHP/MySql ....

Answer (score 0):

I says [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php) in the manual

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: This specific function has been deprecated for much longer than that, though. Other parts of the MySQL extension won't throw deprecation warnings until PHP 5.5 is released, which it hasn't been yet.

Comment: Quote is NOT mine. It's from the manual.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't actually apply to this question. (Also, you haven't provided any fix.)

Answer (score 0):

According to  [**`mysql_list_tables`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php) ...`changelog` secton
This function became deprecated from version 4.3.7
Use `SHOW TABLES`